# Whats wrong with my cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

For some reason This php script won't echo my cookie variable:

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';
    require 'variables.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if(($name == $admin_name) && ($pass == $admin_pass)){
        setcookie($forum_url."name",$name,time()+604800);
        setcookie($forum_url."pass",$pass,time()+604800);
    }

    else
        echo 'Failed';
?>
```

heres the html that gets sent to admin_login.php

```
<form method=post action=admin_login.php>
            <div id="formdiv">
                <div class="fieldtext1">Name</div>
                <div class="fieldtext1">Pass</div> 
                <input type="text" name=name size=25 /> 
                <input type="password" name=pass size=25 />
            </div>
            <input type=submit value="Submit" id="submitbutton">
        </form>
```

here is the index, where I want the info echoed

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE[$forum_url."name"]; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming that on your index page you include the file that defines `$forum_url`, and that you've already checked to see if the cookies are actually being set.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but what you are doing is highly dangerous. You are storing the user's password in clear text in his browser cache.

Comment: To add to @Pekka's statement: one time I looked up my cookies for one website, and found my password stored as plaintext in a cookie. I was very, very upset with the site. Not only is it dangerous, but it makes those who know what they're doing lose significant amounts of trust in your website.

Comment: Try printing out $forum_url . "name" when the cookie is getting set and when you're trying to print out the actual cookie. You can see if you're indexing the array correctly.

Comment: it's printing out the same. Thanks for the idea though, as for the incryption. It's pointless to try and encrypt it now when I can't even get the darn thing to work as plain text. =\

Comment: Use a tool like Firebug to look at the actual HTTP headers being sent and received to narrow down if the problem is with your code or if the browser is not handling the cookies the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `var_dump($_COOKIE)` at the point where you're trying to spit out a specific cookie value? Is it possible that `$forum_url` hasn't been defined yet at the point where you're either setting the cookie, or trying to echo out its value? Perhaps the cookie's been set to `name` and `pass` because `$forum_url` is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the path for the cookie.

If you set cookie in the one path, but you are trying to get it from different path, it won't work.

Can you let me know the URL for the index and where you set cookie?

Comment: they're getting set in the same domain and sub-domain

Answer (score 0):

Also check that the headers haven't already been sent when calling `setcookie()` by asserting that [`headers_sent()`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) returns `false`. Setting a cookie occurs within the HTTP header, so make sure you do so before any output is generated.

For instance:

```
<?php require 'connection.php'; require 'variables.php'; ?>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
<?php setcookie($forum_url."name",$name,time()+604800); ?>
```

Will **not** work, because output has already been passed through to the HTTP body by the time `setcookie()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I set up a quick test and found that when a cookie is stored it replaces periods with underscores.  So if you have a domain like www.test.comname it becomes www_test_comname.  So when referencing the cookie you would need to do something like this:

```
<?php
    $forum_url = preg_replace('/\./','_',$forum_url);
    echo $_COOKIE[$forum_url."name"];
?>
```

<strike>Is it possible that PHP is having a problem concatenating the *$forum_url."name"* and *$forum_url."pass"* in time for setcookie to work properly?</strike>

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';
    require 'variables.php';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $tmp_name_path = $forum_url."name";
    $tmp_pass_path = $forum_url."pass"

    if(($name == $admin_name) && ($pass == $admin_pass)){
        setcookie($tmp_name_path,$name,time()+604800);
        setcookie($tmp_pass_path,$pass,time()+604800);
    }

    else
        echo 'Failed';
?>
```